# in what scenarios should we select java bio or Java nio in networking programming

Tags: java, network-programming, nio

when implementing a messaging server with java, should we select Java bio or Java nio? what factors need to be considered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Tomcat's BIO Connector and NIO Connector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032739/what-is-the-difference-between-tomcats-bio-connector-and-nio-connector)

Answer (score 0):

`NIO` allows you to manage multiple channels (network connections or files) using only a single (or few) threads, but the cost is that parsing the data might be somewhat more complicated than when reading data from a blocking stream.

If you need to manage thousands of open connections simultanously, which each only send a little data, for instance a messaging server, implementing the server in `NIO` is an advantage. Similarly, if you need to keep a lot of open connections to other computers, e.g. in a P2P network, using a single thread to manage all of your outbound connections might be an advantage (`BIO`)

If you have fewer connections with very high bandwidth, sending a lot of data at a time, standard `BIO` server implementation should be your choice.

Read this tutorial for more details

[Java NIO vs. IO](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html)