# Understanding asynchronous web processing

Tags: multithreading, apache, sockets, asynchronous, nginx

I've just finished reading up about asynchronous WebServlet processing. [[This article](http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/blogs/2010/08/13/asynchronous-servlets-in-servlet-spec-3-0/)] is a good read.

However, fundamentally I'm confused why this method is the "next generation of web processing" and is in fact used at all. It seems we are avoiding better configuring our Web Application Servers (WAS) - nginx, apache, tomcat, IIS - and instead, putting the problem on to the Web Developer.

Before I dive into my reasoning, I want to briefly explain how Requests are accepted and then handled by a WAS.

`NETWORK <-> OS -> QUEUE <- WEB APPLICATION SERVER (WAS) <-> WEB APPLICATION (APP)`

1. A Web Application Server (WAS) tells the Operating System (OS) that it wants to receive Requests on a specific Port, e.g. Port 80 for HTTP.
2. The OS opens a Listener on the Port (if it's free) and waits for Clients to connect.
3. When the OS receives a Connection, it adds it to a Queue assigned to the WAS (if there is space, otherwise the Client's Connection is rejected) - the size of the Queue is defined by the WAS when it requests the Port).
4. The WAS monitors the Queue for Connections and when a Connection is available, accepts the Connection for processing - removing it from the Queue.
5. The WAS passes the Connection on to the Web Application for processing - it could also handle the process itself if programmed to.

The WAS can handle multiple Connections at the same time by using multiple Processors (normally one per CPU core), each with multiple Threads.

So this now brings me to my query. If the amount of Requests the WAS can handle depends on the speed at which it can process the Queue, which is down to the number of Processors/Threads assigned to the WAS, why do we create an async method inside our APP to offload the Request from the WAS to another Thread not belonging to the WAS instead of just increasing the number of Threads available to the WAS?

If you consider the (not so) new Web Sockets that are popping up, when a Web Socket makes a connection to a WAS, a Thread is assigned to that Connection which is held open so Client and WAS can have continual communication.  This Thread is ultimately a Thread on the WAS - meaning it is taking up Server resources - whether belonging to the WAS or independent of it (depending on APP design).

However, instead of creating an independent Thread not belonging to the WAS, why not just increase the number of Threads available to the WAS? Ultimately, the number of Threads you can have is down to the resources - MEMORY, CPU - available on the Server.  Or is it a case that by offloading the Connection to a new Thread, you simply don't need to think about how many Threads to assign to the WAS (which seems dangerous because now you can use up Server resources without proper monitoring).  It just seems as if a problem is being passed down to the APP - and thus the Developer - instead of being managed at the WAS.

Or am I simply misunderstanding how a Web Application Server works?

Putting it into a simple Web Application Server example. The following offloads the incoming Connection straight to a Thread.  I am not limiting the number of Threads that can be created, however I am limited to the number of Open Connections allowed on my macbook.  I have also noticed that if the backlog (the second number in the ServerSocket, currently 50) is set too small, I start receiving `Broken Pipes` and `Connection Resets` on the Client side.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090, 50)) {
            while (true) {
                new Run(listener.accept()).start();
            }
        }
    }

    static class Run extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;

        Run(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Processing Thread " + getName());
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println(new Date().toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    this.socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now using Asynchronous, you are just passing the Thread on to another Thread. You are still limited by System Resources - allowed number of open files, connections, memory, CPU, etc..

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090, 100)) {
            while (true) {
                new Synchronous(listener.accept()).start();
            }
        }
    }

    // assumed Synchronous but really it's a Thread from the WAS
    // so is already asynchronous when it enters this Class
    static class Synchronous extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;

        Synchronous(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Passing Socket to Asynchronous " + getName());
            new Asynchronous(this.socket).start();
        }
    }

    static class Asynchronous extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;

        Asynchronous(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Processing Thread " + getName());
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println(new Date().toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    this.socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Looking at this Blog about Netflix '[tuning-tomcat-for-a-high-throughput](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/tuning-tomcat-for-a-high-throughput-fail-fast-system-e4d7b2fc163f)', it looks like Tomcat does the same as my first code example.  So Asynchronous processing in the Application shouldn't be necessary.

Tomcat by default has two properties that affect load, `acceptCount` which defines the maximum Queue size (default: 100) and `maxThreads` which defines the maximum number of simultaneous request processing threads (default: 200).  There is also `maxConnections` but I'm not sure the point of this with `maxThreads` defined. You can read about them at [Tomcat Config](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)

Answer (score 1):

Late, but maybe better than never. :)

I don't have a great answer to "why asych servlets?" but I think there is another bit on information which would be helpful to you.

What you are describing for the WAS is what Tomcat used to do in it's BIO connector.  It was basically a thread per connection model.  This limits the number of requests you can serve not just because of the maxThreads setting, but also because the worker thread would potentially continue to be tied up waiting for additional requests on the connection if a Connection:Close wasn't sent. (See https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/java-concurrency-asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html and [What is the difference between Tomcat's BIO Connector and NIO Connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032739/what-is-the-difference-between-tomcats-bio-connector-and-nio-connector))

Switching to NIO connector allows tomcat to maintain thousands of connections while still maintaining only a small pool of worker threads.

Comment: Thanks delayed or not :)